# Importing Biztalk bindings error

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment

I am trying to deploy Biztalk project to my local Biztalk Server using Biztalk Deployment Framework and i am getting the following error:

> Information: Importing bindings
>   "C:\Users...\PortBindings.xml"
>   into application "Mdm" in BizTalk configuration database
>   (server=".", database="BizTalkMgmtDb")... EXEC : error :
>   Failed to update binding information.
>   [C:\Users...\Deployment.btdfproj]
>   Cannot update receive port "ApprovedRequests".   Cannot update receive
>   location "ApprovedRequestsDb".   The following items could not be
>   matched up to hosts due to name and/or trust level mismatches:
>   Item: 'ApprovedRequestsDb' Host: 'ReceiveHost' Trust level:
>   'Untrusted'   You must do one of the following:
>   1) Create hosts with
>   these names and trust levels and try again
>   2) Re-export the MSI without the binding files and have a post import script apply a
>   suitable binding file.

I've already had host named 'ReceiveHost', so i decided that theres something wrong with Trust level. I tried to deploy with trust level 'Trusted' and recieved the same error.
Can't figure out what is causing the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Ah, the classic untrusted host issue!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the error, in your binding file, the ApprovedRequestsDb receive location is configured to use a host (receive handler) called ReceiveHost, which is untrusted, which BizTalk cannot find.

Double-check the spelling of the host on the local BizTalk server into which you are importing the binding file. Also make sure that it is untrusted.

Finally, the host must be configured as a handler for the adapter used by your receive location. So if your receive location should use the WCF-SQL adapter, then go to the adapter configuration in the BizTalk Administration Console and ensure that the ReceiveHost is configured as a receive handler for that adapter.

Comment: Thank you! That was just the spelling issue :)

Comment: The part I was missing was the adapter configuration. The error doesn't mention this specifically.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check you have a host for this install, in your case called "ReceiveHost".  You can create hosts and host instances in BizTalk Server Admin Console.
2. Check for each adapter (especially the adapter used for "ApprovedRequestsDb") that your bindings use, that "ReceiveHost" host is set up in direction Send/Receive, this will at first likely be only BizTalkServerApplication which is the default.  Under Platform Settings -> Adapters look through these and make new ones where needed to use the "SQL" host.

Answer (score 0):

This error will only ocur if your HostName does not exist or incorrectly spelt. Also check the Trust level is set to Untrusted. Once you have verified the following you can re-create your binding file as ther might be some typo  that is causing it not to import properly.